# redhat linux 6 / disk space at 100% after delete and reboot

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

Using `df -h` and `du` my disk space show 100% all the time. I have deleted at least 2GB of files and I rebooted the server. I thought that will fix the issue as the server came up just fine. However, it still shows disk space  at 100%.

Have anyone has this issue before? I have a tomcat and mysql running on both server. I have stopped those also. I have no idea what to do now?

Comment: best asked at superuser.se

Answer (score 1):

You should find out what directory has grown up to fill your disk.

From root directory, try:

```
# du -sc * | sort -n
```

That will give you an ascending size-ordered list of all the directories in root. Then you should repeat the command from the different directories, until knowing what directory has grown too much.

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) Linux systems actually say that your disk is 100% full if it is in fact 95% full. There is a 5% threshold that is reserved for the root user to write logs and such to keep your system from failing because of local users stuffing the disk. You should only be able to create/write any new files under root and local users should get a "disk full" error.